# Why are these known sports listed in that order?

Tags: pattern, sports

This is a list of known sports:

- Golf
- Tennis
- Baseball
- Bowling
- Basketball

Do you know why they are listed in that order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are listed

> In order of the size of the ball

Answer (score 0):

> From smallest to largest size of “ball” used

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Great answer, although please note that another user has already provided it. Also, in future please use spoiler tags >! to hide all answers so that other puzzlers may also solve this without unwanted hints. Thanks for your contribution and hope to see you contribute elsewhere on the site! :)